# How to get multiple requests at one time to read data from Google Spread Sheet by API

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

i need to retrieve data from Google Sheets by using API. But i have a problem with requesting  different data scopes. As far as my understanding, the scopes i want to get is not returned at a time. I need these below two different data not to request multiple times due to quota limits as described [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits).

The data i need is;

1. Name of all Sheets in the given SpreadSheet
2. Given range of GridData.

The main problem here is i cannot get data those are described above at one time. But i can get them seperatly.

1. I tried [field masks](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/field-masks)(and i couldnt understand very much how its applied in practice. Documentation only explains in theory) it returns only first sheet of whole SpreadSheet.

   ```
      Spreadsheet ExecuteGetQuery(List<string>? Ranges)
      {
          SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = _SheetService.Spreadsheets.Get(_GoogleSpreadSheetIdentifier);
          string fields = "sheets.properties(title)";
          request.Fields = fields;

          if (Ranges != null)
              request.Ranges = Ranges;
          request.IncludeGridData = Ranges != null;

          return request.Execute();
      }
   ```
2. I tried [spreadsheets.getByDataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter) and it's same as above. Each of these methods only returns one data type(GridData i.e. row data, cell data etc. or SheetData i.e. Title of sheet, sheet properties etc.)

   ```
       Spreadsheet ExecuteFilter(SheetsService _SheetServ)
       {
           // The spreadsheet to request.
           string spreadsheetId = "Google Spread Sheet Identifier";  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

           // The DataFilters used to select which ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
           List<Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.DataFilter> dataFilters = new List<Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.DataFilter>();  //  TODO: placeholder value.

           DataFilter df = new DataFilter();

           df.A1Range = "Sheet1!B1:D10:";
           dataFilters.Add(df);
           // True if grid data should be returned.
           // This parameter is ignored if a field mask was set in the request.
           bool includeGridData = false;  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

           // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
           Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest requestBody = new Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest();
           requestBody.DataFilters = dataFilters;
           requestBody.IncludeGridData = includeGridData;

           SpreadsheetsResource.GetByDataFilterRequest request = _SheetServ.Spreadsheets.GetByDataFilter(requestBody,spreadsheetId);

           // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
           return request.Execute();
       }
   ```

The purpose of the question is reduce number of requests to use less quota. But i couldnt figure out how.